# Custom Attribute Filter by option_id and not by label

Tags: product-attribute

I've got a very strange problem. I created a custom attribute named "taille_ecran" which mean in english "screen size". The labels of this attribute are numbers like 1.2, 1.6, 2, 5, 6, etc...

When I try to add a custom filter like this :

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('taille_ecran');
$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'taille_ecran','lteq'=>$_GET['max_size']),
));
```

The filter filters by the option_id of thoses labels in "taille_ecran" instead of labels values. In fact, here is the ID of my labels :

31 => 1.2
41 => 5 etc...

When I tried to get the labels "lteq" under 7 there is no result and when I try 35 I get 1 result which is 1.2.

I try also to print this value in my products list :

```
echo $_product->getTailleEcran();

// print 31 when it's for 1.2...
```

It's very hard for me to explain clearly what is happening. I don't have this problem with other attribute.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fabian and Kiatng here is what I've done to solve this issue. I created a new custom attribute and beside using Drop Down I used Price.

That's permit me to not change my source code and now it's working.

Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'taille_ecran');
$source = $attribute->getSource();
$optionId = $source->getOptionId($_GET['max_size']);
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('taille_ecran', array('lteq'=>$optionId));
```

Comment: Still the same problem. To complete the description of this issue. I'am in list.phtml and I've create a custom product's filter. I added this on top of the file : $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_productCollection->clear();

Comment: Actually, my original answer was wrong. Now edited. $_productCollection->clear() will remove all items in the collection, which is not what you want. So, you should remove that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not supported by magento. Option filters are based on the `option id`, this means you are **not able** to filter by the value.

If you want this, you have to create your own attribute, add it as `decimal` and have your own source model with `value = key`, so you still have a `select` in the backend but you can filter by the value.